# Can Spring Kafka @KafkaListener with @SendTo (read and reply) work with deferred results?

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I need something like this

```
    @SendTo
    @KafkaListener(topics = "some")
    public Future<String> getBatchInfo(String batchCode){
...}
```

Can spring kafka request-reply mechanism work with deferred results?
I tried Future<>, CompletableFuture<>, Mono<> and no one work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. There is no such a feature in Spring for Apache Kafka around that receive-n-reply pattern.

Feel free to raise a GH issue with much more details with the reason behind such a request.

Comment: I need to use ReactiveMongoRepository and Spring WebClient inside receive-n-reply method and don't want to use block.

Comment: Use subscribe() instead and KafkaTemplate in that subscriber manually. That’s probably exactly what we would do implementing this out-of-the-box.

Comment: The GH issue for the whole context : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2325

Comment: Are you propose prepare response Message (with correct headers like correlationId and etc.) manually and send by KafkaTemplate instead @SendTo?

Comment: True. You just create message based on the request : it has all the necessary correlation info in headers.